# ¿Cómo guardar parámetros de un método en una variable?

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo el siguiente código que forma parte de una clase que maneja los eventos de un **frame**:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    if(ae.getSource()== NuevoEstudiante.btnGuardar){

        String nombre= nuevoEstudiante.txtNombre.getText();
        String materia= nuevoEstudiante.txtMatricula.getText();
        String nota= nuevoEstudiante.txtNota.getText();

        String datos= DAO.guardar(
            new Estudiante(nombre, materia, Integer.parseInt(nota))
        );

        if(datos!= null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, datos);
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro Erroneo.");
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando intento guardar los parámetros recibidos en la variable datos:

```
String datos= DAO.guardar(new Estudiante(nombre, materia, Integer.parseInt(nota)));
```

... *NetBeans* me da un error diciéndome:

> incompatible types: void cannot be converted to String

¿Cómo soluciono este error? ¿Debo rehacer mi código de otra forma?

El método `guardar` utilizado forma parte de un *DAO*, es el siguiente:

```
public void guardar(Estudiante e) {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmnt = null;

    try {
        con = dbcon.conectar();

        String sql = "INSERT INTO notas(nombre, matricula, nota) "
            + "VALUES(?, ?, ?)";

        pstmnt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        pstmnt.setString(1, e.getNombre());
        pstmnt.setString(2, e.getMatricula());
        pstmnt.setInt(3, e.getNota());

        pstmnt.execute();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        //System.out.println("Error al conectar a la BD");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al conectar a la BD");
    }finally {
        dbcon.desconectar(con);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El error está en como llamas al método guardar, ya que es un método vacío(Void) lo que puedes hacer es simplemente llamar al método guardar sin crear un String.
tú tienes esto.

```
    String datos= DAO.guardar(new Estudiante(nombre, materia, Integer.parseInt(nota)));
```

Lo dejarías así.

```
   DAO.guardar(new Estudiante(nombre, materia, Integer.parseInt(nota)));
```

Otro consejo, el método guardar deberías volverlo booleano, para que te retorne true o false, dependiendo de si pudo o no insertar el estudiante.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, puede funcionar de la manera como dices, me refiero a que si puede insertar los datos sin ningún problema sin volverlo booleano, es que es para una tarea y el profesor nos dijo que no modificaran los métodos del DAO, además como puedo hacer para enlazar el **if**

Comment: si quieres enlazar el If para que te diga si pudiste insertar o no el estudiante, necesitas modificar el método DAO, así como te dejé, él puede que inserte, como puede que no, la única forma en la que tendrás certeza de ello es modificando el método guardar del DAO, ya sea con que retorne un booleano, o modificando la estructura interna. Sea como sea debes de modificarlo.